# expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant?

Tags: c, linux

I have this header file ... for some reason I keep getting an error saying 
`log_server.h:48: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant`
I get this error on both lines defining the put_evt and print_evt_list functions, 
here's what the code looks like:

```
#ifndef _GENERIC
#define _GENERIC
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#ifndef _NETWORKING
#define _NETWORKING
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
typedef struct sockaddr SA;/* To make casting in the (bind, recvfrom, sendto) more readable */
#endif

#define LOGIN_EVT 0
#define LOGOUT_EVT 1

#define RECV_MSG 27
#define SEND_MSG 64000
#define MAX_EVT_COUNT 3000

struct evt{ 
    char user_name[8];
    int type;
    long int time;
};



/* open log file to append the events to its end
 * return 0 on success and -1 on failure (file could not be opened)
 */
int init_log(const char *log_fname);

/* closes the log file
 * return 0 on success and -1 on failure (file could not be opened)
 */
int terminate_log();

/* add new event to the log file
 * return 0 on success and -1 on failure
 */
int put_evt(struct evt *e);

/* get list of events that occured after the given time
 * count is the size of the allocated and passed e-list
 * return number of found events on success and -1 on failure
 */
int get_events(struct evt  *e_list, long int time);

/* print given event's info (name, time)*/
void print_evt(struct evt  *e);

/* print "count" event's info from the given e_list info (name, time)*/
void print_evt_list(struct evt  *e_list, int count);

/* startListen takes a port number and returns a listening descriptor on sucess or negavtive on error  */
int startListen(int port);

/* Responsbile for hanlding received messages from clients and responding to them accordingly
if the message is an action done, it'll save it in the log file and notify the client
if the message is a query about the events, it'll call the private function queryHandler(); to handle it
returns negative on ERROR*/
int handle_message(int sockDescriptor, struct sockaddr_in *client, char *recvMessage);
```

I've read that this error can be caused by having a preprocessing directive written on  more than one line ... but I don't have that. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Would be handy for you to point out line 48

Comment: To rule out some sort of odd macro / miscellaneous preprocessing oddity, you ought to check the preprocessed output and see if it looks sane.  With `gcc` this can be done using the `-E` flag.

Comment: I already said that the error is given on both functions put_evt and print_evt_list

Comment: @Someone: the `-E` option has been suggested a couple times, but let's try once more:  what does the command `gcc -E sourcefile.c | grep put_evt` say?  (adjust for any options you might need to add for `gcc` to work, such as `-I`).

Comment: this is what it says ... but doesn't really mean anything meaningful :
`int put_evt(struct evt *e); int put_evt(struct evt *e)` @MichaelBurr

Answer (score 18, accepted):

the problem was that I had `struct evt` declared in another location.

Comment: I had the same problem when i had a makefile define with the same name as that of a struct.

Comment: I had the same problem while typedef'ing an error codes enum which happened to have the same identifiers as the ones from [errno](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno).

Comment: I had the same problem with a define in a library overwriting a define in another library, though the define on which the error was reported was not the overwritten one. Instead it reported the error on a define used in the overwritten define. The easiest solution was to move the less dependant library includes after the main library includes so that it could keep the same name without interfering.

Answer (score 14):

I think you have `#define e 2.71828183` or some such in preceding headers.

To find out for sure, run the code through preprocessor and look at the output. In gcc that's -E command line switch

Comment: and the solution to fix it is ... ?

Comment: @Someone: Rename the prototype to take a different parameter name: `void print_evt(struct evt  *ev);`

Comment: Remove the parameter's name from the prototype at all, as it absolutly unnecessary there. @someone

Comment: Then the problem must be something else. Use -E option!

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem, and figured out that `struct evt` was defined in another location

Answer (score 0):

I would try renaming the functions slightly.  Sometimes if one of the headers is defining a token (such as "put_evt") that you use, the preprocessor will mangle your code.

Comment: Its not the functions... its something just after the `(` near the function.